# How to make a bash script work on multiple account?

Tags: scripting

There are several admin-like accounts in our Linux server, different account for different purpose.

Sometimes, there need multi-account co-work to finish a job. Manually, I can login and type the commands. But How can I make it into a single script (BASH)?

BTW: sudo didn't work on my server

Comment: Why did sudo not work?  What errors you get?

Comment: I have no root privilege. So I don't think I can use su.
I can su to other account. But sudo will give me an password error message (password correct for su), and I don't know why.

ALL account are NIS based, not local.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear.  But I believe you are asking how you can run commands that must be performed with other accounts.

Simply do something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute blah as username, assuming the main script is running as root
su username -c blah

# execute blah as username, assumes you have delegated calling users permissions to run command as username
sudo -u username blah

# execute blah as username, using key-based authentication.
ssh username@localhost blah
```

- [man su](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)
- [man sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), [sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Comment: I will try ssh.

Comment: Your other option may be to do something with [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 0):

You must use su -c command to run commands as another user. It will prompt interactively for the password. If you need to run it in batch mode you can use expect.